# javascript timer page up and down won't go to bottom of page

Tags: javascript

I have a timer script which scrolls up and down and repositions the page to the top every 10 seconds and back down every 5 seconds.  My problem is I can't get it to scroll all the way down.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

// Configure refresh interval (in seconds)
var refreshinterval=300

// Shall the coundown be displayed inside your status bar? Say "yes" or "no" below:
var displaycountdown="yes"

var starttime
var nowtime
var reloadseconds=0
var secondssinceloaded=0

function starttime() {
    starttime=new Date()
    starttime=starttime.getTime()
    countdown()
}

function countdown() {
    nowtime= new Date()
    nowtime=nowtime.getTime()
    secondssinceloaded=(nowtime-starttime)/1000
    reloadseconds=Math.round(refreshinterval-secondssinceloaded)
    if (refreshinterval>=secondssinceloaded) {
        var timer=setTimeout("countdown()",1000)
        if (displaycountdown=="yes") {
            window.status="Page refreshing in "+reloadseconds+ " seconds"
        }
        if (timer % 5 == 0) { 
            window.scrollTo(0,1200);
        } 
        if (timer % 10 == 0) { 
            window.scrollTo(0,0);
        } 

    }
    else {
        clearTimeout(timer)
        window.location.reload(true)

    } 
}
window.onload=starttime
</script>
```

How do i get it to scroll all the way down or page down?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is much simpler and achieves what you're looking for:

```
function starttime() {
    setTimeout('scrollDown()',5000);
}

function scrollDown() {
    window.scrollto(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    setTimeout('scrollUp()',5000);
}

function scrollUp() {
    window.scrollto(0,0);
    setTimeout('scrollDown()',5000);
}

window.onload = starttime
```

Comment: you may need to check if document.body.scrollHeight exists first, and if not, use screen.height...   if (document.body.scrollHeight) { window.scrollto(0,document.body.scrollHeight); } else { window.scrollto(0,screen.height); }

Comment: the line window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight); solved my issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your page wouldn't scroll all the way down is probably with your pixel value of 1200. This scrolls the **page** down 1200px, which may or may not be all the way. Heck, your page could be 10000px high or more. Try setting a limit that you can safely know you're page will never surpass, like 20000, and it should scroll all the way to the bottom. :D