# How to automatic scroll up and down went open the page...?

Tags: javascript

I need some help how to create page automatic scroll up and down by itself.
Example for the situation is:

When a user opens the page it will scroll up and down automatically and play by itself without scroll using a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/advwin3.shtml which gives explicit examples on how to programmatically scroll the browser window using javascript.

Another StackOverflow post shows an example of a scrolling script in conjunction with a timer:
[javascript timer page up and down won't go to bottom of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198275/javascript-timer-page-up-and-down-wont-go-to-bottom-of-page/3198330#3198330)